# Go inheritance for Task handling

Tags: go, composition

I am writing a Go slave program that listens on an AQMP message queue for tasks. These tasks contain input data and output data, json encoded.
Different tasks can have completely different input/output structures.

I am trying to find a way to write my registerTask function such that I can re-use that function for multiple tasks and encode JSON to the wanted Input structure. However, the JSON parser should throw an error if the input does not match the specific task input. I tried with accepting interface{}, but that allows anything and makes "foo" validate against any custom struct. Ideas?

This whole composition thing is new to me. In PHP, I would solve this with an abstract base class.

My code so far to register new Tasks:

```
func sendResult(chann *amqp.Channel, task tasks.TaskImpl, output tasks.TaskOutput) error {
    log.Printf("Sending response for %s: %v", task.GetName(), output)

    jsonResponse, err := json.Marshal(output)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Could not encode task %s to JSON: %v", task.GetName(), output)
        return err
    }

    msg := amqp.Publishing{
        DeliveryMode: amqp.Persistent,
        Timestamp:    time.Now(),
        ContentType:  "text/plain",
        Body:         jsonResponse,
    }

    return chann.Publish(QUEUE_RESULT, task.GetName(), false, false, msg)
}

func registerTask(chann *amqp.Channel, task tasks.TaskImpl) {
    log.Println("Registering task: " + task.GetName())

    deliverChann, err := chann.Consume(QUEUE_TODO, task.GetName(), false, false, false, false, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not consume: %v", err)
    }

    go func() {
        for taskMsg := range deliverChann {
            log.Printf("Task received: %v", taskMsg)

            // check if it's in UTF-8
            if strings.ToLower(taskMsg.ContentEncoding) != "utf-8" {
                log.Printf("Warning: task %s is not encoded in utf-8 but: %s", task.GetName(), taskMsg.ContentEncoding)
                taskMsg.Reject(false)
            }

            // check if it's JSON
            if strings.ToLower(taskMsg.ContentType) != "application/json" {
                log.Printf("Warning: task %s is not json but: %s", task.GetName(), taskMsg.ContentType)
                taskMsg.Reject(false)
            }

            log.Printf("Decoding %v", taskMsg.Body)
            if err := json.Unmarshal(taskMsg.Body, &task; err != nil {
                log.Printf("Could not decode task %s body: %v", task.GetName(), err)
                taskMsg.Reject(false)
                continue
            }

            log.Printf("Executing %s with args %v (from %v)", task.GetName(), task, taskMsg.Body)
            output, err := task.Process(input)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Task '%s' error: %s", task.GetName(), err)
                taskMsg.Reject(true)
                continue
            }

            if err := sendResult(chann, task, output); err != nil {
                log.Printf("Could not send result for task: " + task.GetName())
                taskMsg.Reject(true)
                continue
            }

            if err := taskMsg.Ack(false); err != nil {
                log.Println("Could not acknowledge: " + err.Error())
            }
        }
    }()
}
```

And my task code:

```
type TaskInput struct{}
type TaskOutput struct{}

type TaskData interface {
    Input TaskInput `json:"input"`
    Output TaskOutput `json:"output"`
}

type TaskImpl interface {
    GetName() string
    Process(msg *TaskData) (*TaskData, error)
}


type SampleTaskInput struct {
    TaskInput
    Arg string
}
type SampleTaskOutput struct {
    TaskOutput
    Result string
}

type SampleTask struct {
    TaskImpl
}

func (SampleTask) GetName() string {
    return "sample"
}

func (SampleTask) Process(msg *TaskData) (*TaskData, error){

    log.Printf("Executing sampletask with arg: %v", msg.Input)

    msg.Output = SampleTaskOutput{}

    return SampleTaskOutput{
        Result: "String was " + data.Arg,
    }, nil
}
```

Comment: At the time the call to `registerTask` is made, do you know the type of the task? Or are you passing just `nil` as the second argument?

Comment: If you don't know the type of the task before reading the body, you'll have to first read the body, inspect the name, and then based on the name initialize the task implementation you need. For example something like this https://play.golang.com/p/le0iGku58iE

Comment: @mkopriva registerTask is called at initialization and `chann.Consume(QUEUE_TODO, task.GetName()...` will get the task todos.
Every separate task type will launch a separate gofunc.

Comment: In your example code your referencing `input` on this line `output, err := task.Process(input)`, but it's not being declared anywhere, where is that coming from, what is it's type?

Comment: Ahh, my fault, that should be a reference to TaskData. I've been refactoring a lot to make this compile and break it again..

Comment: Have a look at this: https://play.golang.com/p/qBgsGlQkwPZ it should compile unless there is some typo.

Comment: btw. In Go interfaces are satisfied implicitly, you don't need to embed the interface in the implementation (e.g. `type SampleTask struct { TaskImpl }` is unnecessary), you just need to make sure that your SampleTask implements the method set specified by TaskImpl.